# Setting Cookies with XMLHttpRequest2

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to set a cookie using XMLHttpRequest. I'm seeing a "Set-Cookie" header in a response to an XHR post request, but I don't see the cookie in document.cookie. That's fine, though, I ultimately want cookies to not be exposed to the javascript environment, but I'm not seeing any cookies attached to any subsequent post requests from the script, and I thought that cookies were automatically attached to requests by the browser. Is this incorrect? I'm a little confused on whether the cookie is or isn't being set, and I could use some help in figuring this out.

Here is what the client side code looks like:

```
(function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var authUrl= "http://api.myserver.io/cookie"
  xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  xhr.open("POST", authUrl, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.credentials = true;
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      debugger;
      // I'm not seeing anything in xhr.request
    }
  }
  var reqListener = function() {
    debugger;
  }
})()
```

The server code is utilizing expreess and is handling the request with this function:

```
var setCookie = function(req, res) {
  res.cookie('test-cookie', Date.now(), {
    maxAge: 3600000000,
    path:  '/' });
  res.status(200).end()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set `xhr.withCredentials = true`, not `xhr.credentials = true`